# Changing the current property of visibility in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visibility

I have a grid with `Visibility = "Hidden"` and on my .cs i have a function that will change the grid's visibility propert `grid1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;` but it doesnt seem to work. how do i change its visibilty if in XAML it is set to hidden

Comment: Please, show your .cs and .xaml code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it has been a while that I didn't coded in `WPF` but what about binding the visibility to a `bool` in a Model?

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private bool _showGrid;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _showGrid = false;
    }

    public bool ShowGrid        
    {
        get { return _showGrid; }
    }
}
```

and then in `XAML`

```
<Window.DataContext>
  <VM:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>


<Grid Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowGrid, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}">
</Grid>
```

And then just change the value of `_showGrid`

Answer (score 0):

1. I am guessing since you are changing the visiblity by accessing the grid directly in the cs, you are probably not following MVVM.

Anyway, something else might be changing the Visibility, I would add an eventhandler on "IsVisibleChanged" and take it from there,